# Find the point on the cone closest to (1,4,0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the point on the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ nearest to the point $P(1,4,0)$.

This is a homework problem I've not made much headway on.

Comment: Read the solution to Q1 in [this pdf](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~jchavezc/QuizzesMA261f12_files/SolutionsQ6.pdf)

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Is there any technique that you've learned recently that can apply here?  For example, do you know about Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: we've not learned about Lagrange multipliers yet, that is in the next section. Is it necessary for solving this problem?

Comment: @T.Jones it is not necessary but it does make the problem easier.

Comment: We got "lucky," the $z$-coordinate is $0$, so we are minimizing $(x-1)^2+(y-4)^2+x^2+y^2$. Don't even need calculus, complete the squares.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like an exercise in Lagrange Multipliers. You need to minimize the distance function $f(x,y,z) = (x-1)^2 + (y-4)^2 + z^2$ (which is the square distance from $(x,y,z)$ to $(1,4,0)$) subject to the constraint that $g(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$. Any point which minimizes such $f$ subject to the constraint will satisfy $$\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. This gives us 4 equations: \begin{align*} 2(x-1) &= 2\lambda x \\ 2(y-4) &= 2\lambda y \\ 2z&= -2\lambda z \\ x^2 + y^2 - z^2 &= 0.\end{align*} The third equation gives $z = 0$ or $\lambda = -1$. If $z=0$, then the fourth equation gives $x=0, y= 0$. But then the first two equations couldn't be satisfied, so this is impossible. We conclude that $\lambda = -1$. In this case $x = 1/2$, $y=2$ so by the fourth equation $z = \pm\sqrt{17/4}$. By the symmetry in $z$, both sides of the $\pm$ work, so the points which minimize the distance are $$\left(\tfrac 1 2, 2, \sqrt{17/4}\right) \,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,\, \left(\tfrac 1 2, 2, -\sqrt{17/4}\right).$$ The distance is then $$d_{\text{min}} = \sqrt{\left(\tfrac 1 2 - 1 \right)^2 + (2-4)^2 + \left( \pm\sqrt{17/4}\right)^2}= \sqrt{\tfrac 1 4 + 4 + \tfrac{17}4} = \sqrt{\tfrac{34}{4}} = \tfrac{\sqrt{34}}{2}.$$

Comment: NOTE: The above solution by Alex S is much better if you haven't gone over Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 3):

You want to minimize $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-4)^2+z^2}$ where $x$, $y$, and $z$ satisfy $x^2+y^2=z^2$. Notice that if we minimize the distance squared, distance is also minimized, so it suffices to minimize $(x-1)^2+(y-4)^2+z^2$. We can use the constraint to substitute $x^2+y^2$ for $z^2$. On doing so, we get $$(x-1)^2+(y-4)^2+z^2,$$ which expands to $$2x^2+2y^2-2x-8y+17.$$ You can minimize this using usual gradient methods. You will get values for $x$ and $y$. Find $z$ by referring back to the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the scene to come up with an idea:

[image: Cone, Point and two Spheres] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wdmD.png))

The green surfaces belong to the cone, the red and blue surfaces are spheres around $P$.

E.g you could try to find the intersection between cone and sphere and fiddle with the radius to shrink it to a point.

We can describe the intersection by the system
$$
x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0 \\
(x-1)^2 + (y - 4)^2 + z^2 = r^2
$$
This gives
$$
r^2 = (x-1)^2 + (y-4)^2 + x^2 + y^2 = 2x^2 + 2y^2 - 2x - 8y + 17 \iff \\
r^2/2 = x^2 + y^2 - x - 4y + 17/2
= (x - 1/2)^2 + (y-2)^2 + 17/2 - 1/4 - 4 \iff \\
\left(\frac{\sqrt{2r^2-17}}{2}\right)^2 
= \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(y - 2\right)^2
$$
If I made no error, this indicates a circle around $(1/2, 2, 0)$ as projection of the intersection surface onto the $x$-$y$-plane.
Then $z = \pm \sqrt{1/4 + 4} = \pm \sqrt{17}/2$.

That would suggest $Q=(1/2,2,\pm\sqrt{17}/2)$ as closest points, at distance $r = \sqrt{17/2}$.

[image: Contact sphere in orange] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D17dl.png))
[image: Featuring Q2 as well] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa0Hn.png))